# Input an list into a class

Tags: c++

I have written the following code for the box stacking problem however it fails to provide the correct answer and it is mp because of fault in the driver program though I couldn't find it. If I manually write something like

```
Box boxes[] = { {4, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {10, 12, 32} };
```

instead of

```
int N = 4;
    int l[N],b[N],h[N];
    Box boxes[N];
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
    {
       cin>>l[i]>>b[i]>>h[i];
       boxes[i]={l[i],b[i],h[i]};
    }
```

I get the correct result. However I want to take the input from the user so I wrote the following code:
Box is a structure having length breadth and height. Forgive me for my language for I am new to all this!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef struct box {
    int width;
    int depth;
    int height;
} Box;

bool boxComparator(Box b1, Box b2) {
    return ( b1.depth * b1.width > b2.depth * b2.width );
}

int findMaxHeightBoxStack(Box boxes[], int n)
{
    int H[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        H[i] = boxes[i].height;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        for( int j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
            if(boxes[j].width > boxes[i].width 
               && boxes[j].depth > boxes[i].depth 
               && H[j] + boxes[i].height){
                H[i] = H[j] + boxes[i].height;
            }
        }
    }

    int maxHeight = 0 ;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(maxHeight < H[i]){
            maxHeight = H[i];
        }
    }
    return maxHeight;
}

int boxStacking(Box boxes[], int n)
{

    Box orientations[3*n]; //for rotations
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        orientations[index] = boxes[i]; // first one as such
        index++;

        orientations[index].height = boxes[i].width;
        orientations[index].width = max( boxes[i].height, boxes[i].depth) ;
        orientations[index].depth = min( boxes[i].height, boxes[i].depth);

        index++;
        orientations[index].height = boxes[i].depth;
        orientations[index].width = max( boxes[i].height, boxes[i].width) ;
        orientations[index].depth = min( boxes[i].height, boxes[i].width) ;
        index++;
    }
    n = 3*n;

    sort(orientations, orientations+n, boxComparator);
    return findMaxHeightBoxStack( orientations, n);
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    int l[N],b[N],h[N];
    Box boxes[N];
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
    {
       cin>>l[i]>>b[i]>>h[i];
       boxes[i]={l[i],b[i],h[i]};
    }
    int n = 4;
    cout << "Maximum height is " << boxStacking(boxes, N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, provide source code of `boxStacking` function. The computation of height is located there, so if it's incorrect possible the problem is also in implementation of that function.

Comment: I've updated with  it!

Comment: You don’t need `typedef struct …` in C++. In fact, it makes no sense.

Comment: The last term of your if `(... && H[j] + boxes[i].height)` condition checks that `H[j] + boxes[i].height != 0`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes! It wrote it intentionally!

Comment: Please note that `l`, `b` and `h` are declared in `main` as variable length arrays (`N` is not a compile time constant), which are not standard C++. You may either declare `N` as `constexpr` or use `std::vector` if you need a dynamically sized array (like `H` or `orientation` should be).